# CMake and slow MSVC compilation

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, qt-creator

CMake generate project for MSVC 10 (2010) and build time are relativly low, ie. after I click build for given project it start compiling in like seconds, which is expected.

[image: Configuration]
For Qt Creator I choose **CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles** as CMake generator, set build configuration to use the same target as above. When I click build I see 
`cmake --build . --target name`
and silence for like 2 minutes. Then
`Scanning dependencies for ...`
 and 1,5 minutes more of silence.
To make things even worse - later compilation use only 1 thread. So compilation time is ... unacceptably long.

How should I configure project to achieve comparable, short compilation times as from under MSVC? I've tried Qt Creator 4.3 Beta and beside

Comment: Obtain `jom` and try using it instead of `nmake`. Another option is `ninja`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NMake and NMake JOM  are slow.
When I change to Ninja build system - compilation times are similar to those inside MSVC.

Answer (score 9):

CMake per default does not multiprocessor builds. So its up to you to force it to...

You can specify the `/MP` flag when you configure your project with cmake.

`cmake -G "<MSVC-Generator>" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/MP" <target_dir>`

I do this for all my cmake projects in the file CMakeLists.txt itself so the client does not have to:

```
if(MSVC)
 target_compile_options(<target> PRIVATE "/MP")
endif()
```

Comment: Yes, you right.

However - Makefiles generated for NMake contain .NOTPARALLEL  which forces nmake and jom to work in slow serial mode. ninja build system helped.

Answer (score 4):

CMake calls the compiler with default parameters, that is, with a single thread build, even for MSVC. Your build in MSVS is faster because Visual Studio calls the compiler with the settings configured for multiprocessor build.

How to use multiprocessor build for `CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles` or other [cmake generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#id5)?

Add [`-jn` option for `gcc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html) compiler:

```
cmake --build . --target name -- -j4
```

or [`/m` for MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/tuning-c-build-parallelism-in-vs2010/):

```
cmake --build . --target name -- /m
```

For MSVS 2017 or newer instead of `/m` you can use [`-m` form](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference). Also, you can specify the maximum number of concurrent processes to use when building`-m:3`.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, it the flag seems to have changed to `-m`. This makes the full command `cmake --build . --target name -- -m`.

Comment: @Omegastick , from learn.microsoft.com: "Every switch is available in two forms: -switch and /switch. The documentation only shows the -switch form."

Comment: Interesting, the /switch form doesn't seem to work for me, then.

Comment: Hmm, that's curious. I tested in CMD `msbuild -h` and `msbuild /h` - both forms work in MSVS 2017. I did not install MSVS 2019 so can't test this, but maybe MS developers forgot to update documents?

Comment: In CMake 3.19 (and probably some versions prior also), you can specify the `-j` flag directly to CMake itself when running the build command to run in parallel (see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project)